# BookListing project. Each book search overlaps previous results. How do you clear ListView?

Tags: android, listview, fragment, onclicklistener, loader

This is my onClick information:

```
        Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                BookListFragment bookListFragment = new BookListFragment();

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.book_list_frame, bookListFragment).commit();

            }

    });
```

BookListFragment w/BookLoader:

```
    @Override
public Loader<List<BookListing>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle args) {

    return new BookLoader(this, GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL + searchedBook);
}


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<BookListing>> loader, List<BookListing> bookListings) {
    mAdapter.clear();


    if(bookListings != null && !bookListings.isEmpty()) {
        mAdapter.addAll(bookListings);
    }

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<BookListing>> loader) {
    mAdapter.clear();

}
```

I am able to get search results. But when searching again the previous results don't clear. They just continuously overlap.

[First Search Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xZHa.png)
[Second Search Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2IEQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @Override
 public Loader<List<BookListing>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle args) {

 return new BookLoader(this, GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL + searchedBook);
 }


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<BookListing>> loader, 
    List<BookListing> bookListings) {
         mAdapter.clear();


if(bookListings != null && !bookListings.isEmpty()) {
    mAdapter.replace(bookListings);
    }

}
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<BookListing>> loader) {
mAdapter.clear();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding a BookListFragment, use `replace()` instead of `add()`

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.book_list_frame, bookListFragment)
    .commit();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `replace()` instead of `add()`

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.book_list_frame, bookListFragment).commit();
```

That should do it

Comment: repetitive answer?

Comment: @phpdroid i was writing the answer when he posted

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution. Remove all child views (rows) by first getting their parent (ListView).

```
public void removeView(View v) {
    if(v.getParent() != null) {
        ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v);
    }
}
```

Call `removeView(v)` for every row in your ListView. In this case all rows share one parent so try making that parent an instance field and then method above will be:

```
ListView listView;

. . .

public static void removeView(View v) {
    listView.removeView(v);
}
```

You can also remove all rows with one single call by:

```
listView.removeAllViews();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[difference between fragmentTransaction.add and fragmentTransaction.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682248/difference-between-fragmenttransaction-add-and-fragmenttransaction-replace) 
Just further adding onto CamiloCons answer, you're "adding" a new layer of fragments on top everytime you call add().

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something small just could not find an answer anywhere.